# How to limit the results of Firebase Realtime Database to show most recent for pagination?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase real-time database that I push object to. I am trying to implement pagination, such that I can retrieve the most recent 25 entries first followed by further pagination if necessary:, 25 - 50, 50 -75 and so on.

Since I want to retrieve the information as FILO, I am storing a value, "posted", in each of my objects, which is equal to `-1* new Date () .getTime()`. When my react page first loads, I run:

```
this.props.database.ref().child("..." ).orderByChild("posted").startAt(0).limit(this.state.pagination)
```

However, I receive the following error: `.limit is not a function.`

If I run

`this.props.database.ref().child("..." ) or this.props.database.ref().child("..." ).orderByChild("posted")` by itself I retrieve the entire dataset successfully.

How can I retrieve only the last 25 entries from my database?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing an offset value to `startAt` in:

```
orderByChild("posted").startAt(0)
```

This is **not** how `startAt` in the Firebase Realtime Database works.

The value you pass to `startAt` has to be the value of the `posted` property of the node where you want to start.

So if the child you want to start at has `posted` of `-1670622767101`, you'd do:

```
orderByChild("posted").startAt(-1670622767101)
```

If there can be multiple nodes with the same `posted` value, you should pass the **key** of the node to start at as a second value to `startAt`, e.g.

```
orderByChild("posted").startAt(-1670622767101, "-Msdakjsadkasdhkjasd")
```

Comment: What if I don't know what the first value? Is there a way to retrieve this without retrieving my whole dataset?

Comment: Since you mention pagination, the value that you need to pass is based on the previous page. If you don't know the exact value because you only loaded the exact number needed, use `startAfter` rather than `startAt`. So you typically just remember property value + key of the last item of the previous page, and then use them to build the new query.